# Send body with type x-www-form-urlencoded, in Active resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

Using Active Resource I have to send the authentication with the type x-www-form-urlencoded, however it is sending it with the json format:

In my model base

```
self.site = 'http://url.ngrok.io/api'
```

En rails console

```
login = Namespace::Login
login.create username: "username", password: "password"
```

Response

```
ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess: Failed.  Response code = 401
```

In the request continue sending in json format

```
{"username": "username", "password": "password"}"
```

It should be sent this way

```
username=username&password=password
```

Guide me from this tutorial to make a post http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/web_services/active_resource.html

Thank you very much for your help...

Comment: " it is sending it with the json format". Who is sending what where?

Comment: @max At the time of executing in the **rails console** *login.create username: "username", password: "password"*, a post is executed at the endpoint *'http://url.ngrok.io/api'*, in **json format**